# magento add to wishlist message in product details page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to show Wishlist Success Message in the product details page. I have change the redirection part. Now my page is redirecting to same page after added the product to wishlist. But I need to Show the message in same page. Kindly Help.. Thanks in advance. P.S.- I don't want to use ajax add to wishlist functionality.

Comment: if you know that it will possible through ajax functionality then why did you posting such question here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @sagar: because I need to update this functionality in page load.. The message is coming for the homepage now.. But I need to remove that message this part.. I can use module but there are certain thing what you find to gather your knowledge.. It's not bad I think..

Comment: @ Enigmativity: Please let me know how you belief that question is not related to Programming.. I need proper coding solution for that part..

Comment: Please note your magento version.

Comment: I appreciate that but the way of asking solution is not good.Thanks in advance. P.S.- I don't want to use ajax add to wishlist functionality. Do you think any programmer like such kind of posting. No one you should least try to understand all proposed solution.

Comment: Sorry for that. But I think I'm not taking any literature class here.If it make you feel sad, I am sorry for that. But we come here or we post here believing only one thing - for some better solution. Ok.. Ignore it. But the funniest thing is you are arguing except giving me a solution.

Comment: @sagarumaretiya Sarcasm that you cared to waste your time in arguing rather then giving a solution. Be kind and helpful and if you cant then better dont comment atleast! It is always possible that beginners do come here to get some solutions if they do not get any pre-existing idea, so please be generous rather then rude..

Comment: @AnuragKhandelwal, Thanks for your comment and advice. I have preposition for you before you make a comment on anybody you should have at least look at your own score. I've been answering here since more then 1.5 years and i did well job. As far as rude is concern i didn't like the way candidate had aargy. In addition to this i know very well where i should spare my time so better is mind your own business.thanks!

Comment: @sagarumaretiya May God bless you!

Comment: @AnuragKhandelwal, you're welcome. I wish same for you. Have a great life.

Answer (score 0):

The Magento Session models i.e. core/session, customer/session and catalog/session etc.

To add a message you can use "app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\controllers\IndexController.php":

Action : addAction()

Find :

```
$session->addSuccess($message);
```

below write this code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addSuccess($message);
```

Then add error message :

Find :

```
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $session->addError($this->__('An error occurred while adding item to wishlist: %s', $e->getMessage()));
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->addError($this->__('An error occurred while adding item to wishlist.'));
        }
```

replace with below code :

```
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $session->addError($this->__('An error occurred while adding item to wishlist: %s', $e->getMessage()));
            $error_msg = $this->__('An error occurred while adding item to wishlist: %s', $e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addError($error_msg);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->addError($this->__('An error occurred while adding item to wishlist.'));
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addError('An error occurred while adding item to wishlist.');
        }
```

If "catalog/session" is not working please try "core/session".